# why is the string "almostomla" not giving out false as it should?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to code a pelindrome checker. every other word was returned correctly except this specific word. I have checked my code over and over again but keep getting true. Have I here made any mistake?

```
var speSym = /_|\./g;

function palindrome(str) {
  var newStr1 = str.toLowerCase();
  var newStr = newStr1.replace(speSym, "" );

  if (newStr.length % 2 != 0){
    for(var i = 0; i <= (newStr.length - 1) / 2; i ++){
      if(newStr[i] == newStr[newStr.length - (i + 1)]){

        return true;

      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  if(newStr.length % 2 == 0){
    for(var j = 0; j <= (newStr.length - 2) / 2; j ++){
      if(newStr[j] == newStr[newStr.length - (j + 1)]){

        return true;

      }
      else{

        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(palindrome("almostomla"));
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind differentiating words based off of whether or not they are of even/odd length?  Just a quick guide to writing palindromic algorithims; you can usually just simply reverse loop the word and check it against the original input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function palindrome(str) {
  var newStr1 = str.toLowerCase();
  var newStr = newStr1.replace(speSym, "" );

  if (newStr.length % 2 != 0){
    for(var i = 0; i <= (newStr.length - 1) / 2; i ++){
      if(newStr[i] === newStr[newStr.length - (i + 1)]){

        return true;

      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  if(newStr.length % 2 == 0){
    for(var j = 0; j <= (newStr.length - 2) / 2; j ++){
      if(newStr[j + 1] === newStr[newStr.length - (j + 1)]){

        return true;

      }
      else{

        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Adding to your conditional like so (`newStr[j + 1]`) seems to give you the functionality you are looking for.  It looks like you were missing a comparison of an individual letter, which was causing some hiccups when the length of the word is even.  This should work.

Although I don't normally post other solutions, as a new programmer (I still am), seeing other people's work helps me a out a ton.  In this case, a reverse loop is perfect for palindromes like so:

```
function palindrome(word){
    let reverseWord = []
    for(let i = word.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        reverseWord.push(word[i])
    }
    return word === reverseWord.join("") ? true : false
}   

console.log(palindrome("almostomla"))
```

Comment: Oh Thank you so much! I cannot fully understand what's going in the solution given by you, but i definitely get the idea.

Comment: Not a problem!  My solution is simply looping through the word backwards.   As I loop through the word, I am pushing each letter into an array.  From there, I join the elements from the array into a string and compare it to the original input.